# magit-grep, how to include or exlude file extensions?

Tags: git, emacs, grep, magit

I'd like to give some options to magit-grep

running it with option `foo` results in

```
git --no-pager grep -n foo
```

I'd like to give options to it

```
git --no-pager grep -n foo (options to include *.html and exclude *.py, etc)
```

It doesn't have to be magit-grep,  what's the best git grep solution in emacs?

---

magit-grep

```lisp
(magit-define-command grep (&optional pattern)
  (interactive)
  (let ((pattern (or pattern
                     (read-string "git grep: "
                                  (shell-quote-argument (grep-tag-default))))))
    (with-current-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*Magit Grep*")
      (let ((default-directory (magit-get-top-dir)))
        (insert magit-git-executable " "
                (mapconcat 'identity magit-git-standard-options " ")
                " grep -n "
                (shell-quote-argument pattern) "\n\n")
        (magit-git-insert (list "grep" "--line-number" pattern))
        (grep-mode)
        (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))))))
```

Comment: I think just `git grep 'expression' -- '*.html'` should do. Maybe you could extend this function to ask you for the file masks if given universal argument.

Answer (score 14):

I have removed `magit-grep`, as it was just a severely crippled version of `rgrep`. `vc-git-grep` is actually an improvement, so you should use that. (Nowadays `magit-grep` is defined as an alias for the vc command, to avoid disturbing anyone who previously used the magit variant. A classic case of "add features by looking what already exists elsewhere and then remove our code" :-)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is a combination og `git-grep` and `git-ls-files`:

```
git grep ... `git ls-files | grep -- '\.html$'`
```

But this works only if the output of `git-ls-files` does not exceed the maximum command line size on your system (which is a couple of 100K on modern systems).